# pairwise.t.test function and t-value

Tags: r

I have been using the pairwise.t.test function and I can't seem to obtain the t-value for any of the methods of adjustment that pairwise.t.test allows. Does anyone know a way of obtaining the t-value for the pairwise comparisons or is there another function that gives me a more complete picture instead of just a p-value?

This question is different than similar questions that have been previously asked. The common answer has been "no" when asking about obtaining t-values from the pairwise.t.test function. I am wanting to know if anyone has a better recommendation for a function, when conducting pairwise comparisons in ANOVA, to obtain the t-value.

Comment: Thank you, Pascal. I read that answer prior to typing my question. It isn't a duplicate because that answer was simply saying "no". I am asking if anyone knows of another function that can provide me with t-values for the pairwise comparisons of an ANOVA.

Comment: If you read that question prior to post, please cite this question or others.

Comment: It looks like you would have to run through the source code of `pairwise.t.test` line by line, then save the t-value yourself.

Comment: Scott, thanks. Do you happen to have an example of how I could do this? Not familiar with how to run through the source code.

Comment: See [How can I view the source code for a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function) for example.